# Difference between query a database through an EF context versus Web API

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

I currently have a WinForms app that uses Entity Framework to communicate with a SQL database that is on the local network.  This is nice because I can create a database context and then use LINQ to manipulate my data.

I'm building an MVC app that will be hosted in a different location but will need to access the same database used by the WinForms app.  I was hoping I could expose the data through a Web API, but as I've started doing this it looks like I have to construct URLs to return the data that I need from the API rather than being able to communicate through a context object like I'm accustomed to doing.

For example, if I want to get all the roles a user is currently in I can do something like this:

```
var roles = from u in ctx.user where u.Id == 1 select u.Roles;
```

If I'm understanding correctly, if using Web API I have to construct a URL with all my parameters, create an HTTP request using HttpContext, then get my results from the response.  Is this correct?

Comment: `Entity Framework` has nothing to do with the `Web API`. You can use `DbContext`, you can also use service to communicate with the database. Maybe you got the wrong impression because the `Web API` is usually used for `SOA` applications.

Comment: @Leron I think he's asking about why you would choose to implement a Web API vs just accessing the database directly (using EF in this case, but possibly also via ADO.NET).

Comment: Just one note: you should move database logic out of client side (WinForms app) - database login and password could be reversed engineered (cause that data lies in binary).

Comment: @mason Still I see no connection and I think that the OP got some things wrong. Right now I'm working on a project where I use `ashx` files as Http Handlers and I clearly see where the power of the `Web API` lies - when you need to deal with a loft `HTTP` request/responses but still, when you go on the server side, say the `Web API` controller there's no problem in using `EF` or whatever you need according tou your project design.

Comment: @mason Accessing the database directly isn't an option which is why I wanted to expose the EF model via Web API. Leron - EF may not have anything to do with Web API in a strict sense, but in my implementation it does. I created an EF model for model database and then scaffolded out controllers for each object in the model (table in the database, in this case). Perhaps I'm just spoiled being able to work with my data through a context, easily querying for what I want, making changes, and then calling ctx.SaveChanges() to update the database. It looks like with Web API I'll have a lot more work.

Comment: @FDRob It might be more up front work to add that layer. But once it's done, you don't have to implement that part again if you want to add another client.

Comment: @mason Adding that layer isn't really the part the concerns me.  Consuming it seems to be the part that will be tedious.

Comment: @FDRob Well, programming is tedious work anyways. But any sufficient level of abstraction makes it seem like magic. So you just need to find a good library that abstracts away the tough parts, like the one I put in my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mostly correct. Using Web API adds an additional layer here. What's nice is that you can move a lot of logic from your application into the API layer and have a cleaner Separation of Concerns. This means you could add additional clients (perhaps that don't support EF or may not even be .NET based, such as iPhone apps) that talk to the same Web API.

Note it doesn't necessarily have to be the URL that contains the parameters, they can be in the request body. And [there are frameworks](http://restsharp.org/) that can automate creating your requests for you when you provide your strongly typed parameters. You don't use HttpContext (which is an ASP.NET thing for the server side anyways, not the client).

Comment: How comes that `Web API` changes the behavior of `Entity Framework`? The additional layer you are talking about refers to the `Http Handler` and not to the way you deal with you data base.If indeed `Web API` had something to do with `Entity Framework` then we would have had problem with the separation of concerns. Don't you think?

Comment: @Leron I think you're confused. Or you're trying to make some point that is confusing the situation. Web API doesn't change the behavior of EF. It's a server side library for receiving calls over HTTP connections, and returning responses. To processes those responses and generate requests there might be some data access involved, where the Web API server can use EF or ADO.NET or any other data access technology.

Comment: @mason You said " You don't use HttpContext (which is an ASP.NET thing for the server side anyways, not the client)."  That wouldn't be true if my client is a .NET application, would it?  If so, how else would I call the API from a .NET client?

Comment: @FDRob you don't use HttpContext on client side. Depending on the client it will provide different request and response objects. See the link in my answer.

Comment: @mason Yeah, sorry...I kept saying HttpContext but what I was intending to say was HttpClient.

Comment: @FDRob You can use `HttpClient` if that's the library you want to use.

Comment: @mason I can't say that I "want" to use it, but it appears to be the out-of-the-box method.  I looked at RestSharp and it appears to be a cleaner option, but neither option gives me what I was hoping.  I've used WCF Data Services (a little) in the past and I guess I didn't appreciate the goodness provided by its client side LINQ provider that exposed the EF model to the disconnected client.  I suppose if I want that functionality I need to use WCF Data Services.  Problem is, Microsoft has stated they are focusing on Web API and releasing WCF Data Services to the community to be maintained. :(

Answer (score 0):

Web API is just an easy way to create web services. You wouldn't necessarily need to include the parameters in your URL, you could use a HTTP post and include the parameters in the request body, but you won't have the ability to just run LINQ queries on your web methods like you would with Entity Framework.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest extracting the "Data layer" out. If all of your EF calls were done in the newly extracted data layer then you could use the same calls for both projects. Create a new project and do all of your calls from this layer. See [Repository Pattern.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649690.aspx)

Now with that layer extracted you can do anything. You could have a web api call the individual methods in the Repository layer or you could use built in MVC ActionResults to handle this.

Side Note: You may want to look into [Dependency Injection.](http://www.dotnet-tricks.com/Tutorial/dependencyinjection/67LX120413-Implementation-of-Dependency-Injection-Pattern-in-C) It will make the process easier and smoother.